# error with hex-color in inline SVG in chrome 72

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I'm curious if someone knows why the newest chrome (v72) has problems showing inline SVG with hex-color codes? chrome v71 has no problems.

please try and put this into the uri-field

NOT WORKING:

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><path d="M1 0 L0 1 M0 0 L1 1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="15px" stroke="#dd4b39" opacity="0.8"/></svg>
```

WORKING:

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><path d="M1 0 L0 1 M0 0 L1 1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="15px" stroke="red" opacity="0.8"/></svg>
```

I changed only the hexcode for 'stroke'.

thanks for any hints.

Comment: because chrome decided to finally follow the correct way :) .. you need to encode the # -->  `%23` (edit: not able to find the related question)